# symfony2 collection type - remove/delete replace other element in collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I would like to understand how the collection type is handled in Symfony2. I'm using Symfony 2.4.6 and Sonata Admin 2.2.11.

So, I've got a Banner entity which has got relation OneToMany to files. It's working fine when I add or remove files separately, but if I'm going to do it on the same update it will get messy.

For example:

1. When I get to edit a banner I have 3 files: file1, file2, file3, file4
2. Remove file3
3. Add file5
4. Click update

The output will be: file1, file2, file5 (file4 was replaced by file5).

I couldn't find any reference to the file id in the collection type, so how should Symfony know which collection to delete?

Thanks for any explanation.

My entities looks like:

```
class Banner  
{  
    /.../  

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BannerFile", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="banner", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $bannerFiles;  


    /.../  

    /**
     * Remove bannerFiles
     *
     * @param BannerFile $bannerFiles
     */
    public function removeBannerFile(BannerFile $bannerFiles)
    {
        $this->bannerFiles->removeElement($bannerFiles);
    }
}  

class BannerFile
{
    /.../  

    /**
     * @var integer $banner
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(fetch="EXTRA_LAZY", inversedBy="bannerFiles", targetEntity="Banner")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="banner_id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $banner;  
}
```

Comment: The Collection is just an abstraction presented as an array so that PHP or Twig can iterate over it using things like `foreach`. The IDs of the files are stored in the individual objects inside of the collection. What you're describing sounds like either a bug with Sonata Admin (in which case you should [make a new issue in the project](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/new)) or bad Association Mapping on the Doctrine side of things. Could you post your entities?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have edited my original question to include entities.

So, collection is holding elements as an array but in the collection form I couldn't see any references to an object so it looks like it does actually iterate through an array and it's just matching first element in a form to first element in array. But I can't believe that this could be done this way so, or could it?